# iText xmlWorker top margin

Tags: html-parsing, itext, margin

When i run this code, I get a margin at the top of the document.

[image]

And I have no idea on how to get rid of it. I'm running the latest versions of iText and XMLWorker.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5.rotate(), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("E:/itext/test.pdf"));
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);

cssResolver.addCss("p{color: #a00; font-size: 20pt; margin: 0; padding: 0;}", true);

Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

document.open();

String htmlData = "<html> <p>Lorem ipsum</p> </html>";

xmlParser.parse(new StringReader(htmlData));

document.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML `<p>` tag normally has padding above and below. Perhaps you'll get the result you're looking for if you use a `<div>` tag instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the margins on document object.

```
document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Have you seen that the OP used `0f, 0f, 0f, 0f` in the corresponding `Document` constructor parameters?